What is the most efficient method for regularly querying a relational database:Prepared Statement, Stored Procedure, User Defined Function or another?
In a system where users can generate SQL reports based on specified parameters, such as time filters and company filters, and where the data needs to be updated regularly from a relational database, what is the most performant method for retrieving data parametrically? Considerations should include using prepared statements, stored procedures, user-defined functions, or other methods, while also addressing potential security and privilege concerns.
For example, let's create a report for the Order table: Let it be time filter, Cargo Company filters. I would like to see the cargo delivered today by FedEx cargo in Istanbul. Then i set it to update the data every 1 minute.
I expect to find generic and effective way of doing sql report while creating sql statement
